# Minimized javascript throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+20AC in Firefox only

Tags: javascript

I'm having a weird issue specifically with the webpack minimized version of our app, only on Firefox. It works fine in debug in Firefox, and works fine on other browsers. When trying to load the minimized JS file, it's failing and throwing an error to the console:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+20AC _initclonebytag.js:12:19`. This is a function coming from lodash, so I'm unsure why it would be causing any issues.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We finally found the problem this morning. The one page where it was occurring was getting its encoding switch to something other than UTF-8 as a side effect of another component. We fixed that side effect and now it's fine.

Comment: where exactly was the problem?

in the html file ?

Comment: So we are bolting modern react onto an existing Struts 1 application, and on one of the struts pages, one of the 3rd party date controls was messing up the encoding when rendered on the server.